# What if request is sent and response ia not recieved

Tags: android, networking, retrofit

I am making an android application where I have a scenerio where i have got some data . there is a field called sync which becomes true when i get response from server. But sometimes request is sent to server and data is stored on the server but i dont get the response and nxt time all the data where sync is false is sent to server resulting in duplication.. The app is used in multiple devices so cant have any local database field as a primary key on server.
So how can i handle this thing from app side.

I am using Sugar orm for database and retrofit for rest api

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be waiting for confirmation of receipt of data before you end your task, if no response is received then you can either try again or cancel the sending.

Sending data and not awaiting response is not ideal!

Comment: Your ans doesnt seems to be practical one !! Let me explain you !! If i dont recieve any response that means exception is created. But the thing is my data is saved on server and because i didnt recieved or some how lost the response i will send the request again which will result in duplication of data